# Change port for http to https -- Nginx

Tags: nginx

Sorry for limited understanding on Nginx, Iam new to Nginx.
I have a webapp running on React and Nginx. Recently I received the SSL certificates for my website. I tried to configure the website and it worked partially. The problem is when I tried to open "https://example.com", the SSL certificates are visible here but its showing nginx default home page. While when I open "http://example.com" it shows all the webcontent.

I attempted to:

1. change the port from 80 to 443
2. Reinstall nginx.
   But nothing seems to work. Here is my nginx confs at the moment:

/etc/nginx/sites-available/example.org

```
server {
    listen 443;
    listen [::]:443;
    
    ssl on;
    ssl_certificate /etc/nginx/ssl/bundle.cer;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/nginx/ssl/example.key
    
    root /var/www/html;
    
    server_name example.org;
    
    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
    }
}

server {
        listen 80;
        listen [::]:80;
        
        server_name _;
        return 301 https://example.org;
}
```

/etc/nginx/conf.d/www/example.org.conf

```
server {
    listen 80 default_server;
    server www.example.org;
    
    location / {
        root /usr/share/nginx/html;
        index index.htm; index.html;
    }
}
```

**Note:** I reload nginx at every new attempt.
Please help where am I going wrong.

Comment: Why you have 2 configs ?

Comment: I followed a few document over the google. Sorry for the misunderstanding of the concepts. Should I have to remove any one of it?

Comment: You are right. That was my bad, I followed too many of blogs and documents to messed it up. I kept conf at sites-available, and now it works. Thanks Amin

Comment: Glad to hear that. Note that `site-available` approach is deprecated as nginx docs says. Put your config in `conf.d`

Answer (score 0):

Keeping just 1 file for config works for the above problem. I kept the "default" conf at "/etc/nginx/sites-available"